# XCode compile: "undeclare use of cin" how do i fix it?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

I've been using Xcode 10.0 on my mac and whenever I use *cin*, the compiler shows an error:

```
|6|error: use of undeclared identifier cin|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

However, `cout` and other c++ built-ins are working just fine...

A few days ago I have commented out some header file in gcc's header file folder for another bug. (Is there any chance to create this problem for what I've done before with the header file folder?)

Comment: Please provide a [repro] demonstrating the error.

Comment: Also: "*few days ago i have comment out some header file on gcc compiler's header file folder*": What does that mean? Did you modify the header files distributed with the compiler? Never ever do that. If you did, remove and install the compiler again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
#include <iostream>
```

to be able to use `std::cin`. If you want to avoid the `std::` namespace prefix, add

```
using std::cin;
```

to your code as well.

Comment: #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
cout<<n;
return 0;
}

i know that but it's my xcode compiler's problem may be....
above code in an example.... if i run the code then shows me undeclare use of cin
some also it show ... do you mean min by cin?
i think some how my compiler miss the build in cin function... but how to fix this?

Comment: @MrHabib Don't *ever* `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058). And `using namespace stdc;` is also rather bad practice - *especially* after that other header drags in everything and the kitchen sink.